# Big MySQL performance difference between master and slave

Tags: mysql, performance, explain

I have a MySQL cluster:(master, two slaves). **Recently**（7 days）, I encountered a strange problem: The same SQL has different costs on different db hosts.
This problem only happened on **several** tables；

I want to know why and how to solve this problem.
 **Master cost 2.47sec**

```
mysql> explain select id from notification_message where expire_time < '2015-07-23' limit 1\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: notification_message
         type: range
possible_keys: idx_expire_time
          key: idx_expire_time
      key_len: 6
          ref: NULL
         rows: 5414595
        Extra: Using where; Using index
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>  select id from notification_message where expire_time < '2015-07-23' limit 1\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
id: 186925000
1 row in set (2.47 sec)
```

**Slave cost 0.00sec**

```
mysql> explain select id from notification_message where expire_time < '2015-07-23' limit 1\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: notification_message
         type: range
possible_keys: idx_expire_time
          key: idx_expire_time
      key_len: 6
          ref: NULL
         rows: 4999367
        Extra: Using where; Using index
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select id from notification_message where expire_time < '2015-07-23' limit 1;
+-----------+
| id        |
+-----------+
| 186925000 |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Here is the mysql version**

Master server version:
"Server version: 5.6.15-56-log Percona Server (GPL), Release rel63.0, Revision 519"

Slave server version:
"Server version: 5.6.22-71.0-log Percona Server (GPL), Release 71.0, Revision 726"

**Here is the hardware**

master same as slave:
       os core： Linux 2.6.32-431.20.3.el6.mt20150216.x86_64
          OS： CentOS
    CPU    ： Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2630 v2 @ 2.60GHz
    CPU num： 24
        ram： 130GB
       RAID： ( raid1 , SAS [1TB*2] 1TB)( raid5 , SSD [480.0GB*6] 2.4TB)

[image: load of master]
[image]

Comment: master: `os core： Linux 2.6.32-431.20.3.el6.mt20150216.x86_64
      OS： CentOS
 CPU    ： Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2630 v2 @ 2.60GHz
 CPU num： 24
     ram： 130GB`

slave: `os core： Linux 2.6.32-431.20.3.el6.mt20150216.x86_64
      OS： CentOS
 CPU    ： Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2630 v2 @ 2.60GHz
 CPU num： 24
     ram： 130GB`
    RAID： ( raid1 , SAS [1TB*2] 1TB)( raid5 , SSD [480.0GB*6] 2.4TB)

Comment: barring any need to run `analyze table` for statistics refresh, and I certainly wouldn't recommend it willy nilly on 5M rows, the master is hardly sitting around to the extent that slave is (or was). Focus on the likes of linux `top` command.

Comment: The db server has 5+ databases, 100+tables. Only several tables encounter this problem

Comment: acting as a dbserver may be only one part of what it does. also, the sampling during the day. also my first highlight above. what `explain` says it is going to do could be quite different from what it does.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` -- The Explain says `Using index`; we need to see that index.  Also, why is `Key_len` 6 bytes?  That does not make sense for a date.  Again the `SHOW` will clarify.

Comment: It is rather meaningless to have a `LIMIT` without an `ORDER BY`.  I worry that you 'simplified' your _real_ query to the point where any answer here will not transfer to the real query.

Answer (score 0):

(Remark too long for the comment box):

There is still some information missing:

> Master and slave mysql configuration, then mainly memory and disk data location (what if one DB lives on SSD and the other on SAS 1TB disks)
>
> No load information on the master & slave: Install tooling like cacti with percona plugin.

To get a better test of the query time: Take care to run in a "fresh" instance: Type `flush query cache` on the **slave** and retest the query. This will create a situation where all data has to be loaded from disk.

Usually testing this way on the master is a no since it will slow down the system for a while (re-loading all data from disk to warm the cache takes time (up to several hours depending on the load)).

Comment: Actually, master has the same hardware as the slave.

Comment: Same hardware: Yes, setup of the hardware: Is the database really on the disk where it should be (same disk type master & slave), load of the systems, that is where the differences can occur with the same hardware.

Comment: `master load: $ w
 11:36:55 up 112 days, 16:24,  2 users,  load average: 1.25, 1.39, 1.40`

`slave load: w
 11:38:02 up 112 days, 14:05,  1 user,  load average: 2.04, 1.91, 1.94`

Comment: Interesting that the slave load is higher then the master load (not impossible but interesting), This is just a moment in time, so install something like cacti. Takes you about 1 hour, but gives you way more information on what is happening. Also: Post the mysql settings (pretty much: All in the configuration file) in you post please.

Comment: Ok, later I will post load stat, select count per min.